# eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e) does not detect right object

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, qevent, eventfilter

I expect my program to print "mouse on label name" when my mouse is located on the `labelname` (a `QLabel`), and to print"mouse not on label name" when my mouse is not located on the `labelname`.

Even though I put my mouse on `labelname`, my program prints "mouse not on label name".

How can I know when my mouse is not on the `labelname`?

```
bool Dialog::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *e)
{
    if(qobject_cast<QLabel*>(obj) == ui->labelname) {
    cout << “mouse on label name” << endl;
    }else if(qobject_cast<QLabel*>(obj) != ui->labelname) { 
    cout << “mouse not on label name” << endl;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Have you "installed" this eventFilter to ui->lablename? or just reimplemented this function in Dialog class?

Comment: I just reimplemented this function in dialog class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure you are installing the [event filter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#eventFilter) correctly. Also, if you want to track mouse position you have to enable [`mouseTracking`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop), otherwise the move events won't be triggered (though `QEvent::Enter` and `QEvent::Leave` will, which are [the ones](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qevent.html#Type-enum) that indicates the mouse has entered or left the widget).

Here a minimal example of how to do it:

```
MyWidget::MyWidget(QWidget *parent)
  : QWidget(parent)
{
  m_label = new QLabel("Hello world!");
  m_label->setObjectName("m_label");
  m_label->installEventFilter(this);
  m_label->setMouseTracking(true);

  auto hlayout = new QVBoxLayout();
  hlayout->addWidget(m_label);
  setLayout(hlayout);
}

bool MyWidget::eventFilter(QObject* sender, QEvent* event)
{
  if (sender == m_label) {
    qDebug() << sender->objectName() << event->type();

    if (event->type() == QEvent::Enter) {
      qDebug() << "mouse on label name";
    } else if (event->type() == QEvent::Leave) {
      qDebug() << "mouse not on label name";
    }
  }

  return QWidget::eventFilter(sender, event);
}
```

The full working example is available in [GitHub](https://github.com/cbuchart/stackoverflow/tree/master/56677525-eventfilterqobject).